# CartThrob Notifications - Multiple To Emails

Tags: cartthrob

I recently launched a EE site using CartThrob. I need to add multiple email addresses to a notification, the 'Email To' field. Here is a screenshot of the settings available (http://cl.ly/image/2Y2I1s1w441V). The 'Email To' field doesn't mention if you can add multiple emails. I aslo searched the CartThrob documentation but couldn't find anything either. I am guessing you might be able to separate emails using a comma.

Can you add multiple emails to the 'Email To' notification field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use a comma separated string, you could probably achieve the same thing by duplicating the notification and just using a different email address for each one. Because you can create as many different notifications as you like and there's nothing to say that you can't have more than notification for the same event.

Comment: I forgot I still had a staging site setup. I tested the feature there. Yes, you can use commas to send a notification to multiple emails.

Comment: Another alternative would be to send to an alias address and split it to different people from there, which is what I've done for future-proofing purposes a few times.